# Determine if Azure Deployments exist for the Specified Service and Slot

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I'd like to know if it is possible to determine if a deployment is present for a given service (and the respective slot (`Production` or `Staging`)).

All I found would be to call `Get-AzureDeployment -ServiceName xxxservice` which would throw an error saying `Get-AzureDeployment : ResourceNotFound: No deployments were found.` in PowerShell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try -ErrorVariable and -ErrorAction parameters

```
$deployment = Get-AzureDeployment -ServiceName $serviceName -Slot $slot -ErrorVariable a -ErrorAction silentlycontinue 
if ($a[0] -ne $null)
{
    Write-Output "$(Get-Date –f $timeStampFormat) - No deployment is detected."
}
```

Comment: no, $a[0] is the first error returned by Get-AzureDeployment (if any)

Comment: It's not a clean decision. What if some other error happened? We just hide it with "-ErrorAction silentlycontinue"